# Reset Editor layout in Unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I have pressed something on Mac OS, and now I can't put all windows together (docking). In Windows OS we simply drag another window to tabs space and we have 2 tabs. In Mac OS we can't do it. Is there any reset in Unity?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you locked it. If the Inspector tab is not showing the latest object you select then unlock it by clicking on the padlock icon:

[image]

> Is there any reset in Unity?

To reset the Editor layout, click on the Default dropdown button then select the Default option. It should reset the Editor layout to the default layout mode.

If this doesn't work, click on the Default dropdown button then click on "Revert Factory Settings..." to restore it to its factory settings.

[image]

Comment: Ty very much! You won't beleive it but this one also fixed Unity crash on trying to open color picker popup.