# How can I copy key frames from one animation clip to another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is when I'm selecting the keyframes with the mouse when I leave the mouse left button the selected keyframes are not selected and I can't make any copy like Ctrl + C.

[image: Selected with the mouse left button click and dragging.]

[image: When leaving releasing the left mouse click the selected keyframes are not selected.]

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+ click to select multiple keyframes, or select one keyframe then shift + click and select another to select all keyframes in between.

If it's a UI bug, [try resetting the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257096/reset-editor-layout-in-unity#:%7E:text=To%20reset%20the%20Editor%20layout,it%20to%20its%20factory%20settings.)

Otherwise it may be a broken mouse button.